# Firebase Sign in with apple. New user and returning user

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, sign-in-with-apple

I have implemented sign in with apple. I initiate the first time user this way:

```
let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com",
                                          idToken: idTokenString,
                                          rawNonce: nonce)
```

then sign in the user:

```
// HERE: Auth.auth().currentUser is always nil for first time users AND returning users
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
     // HERE: Auth.auth().currentUser is never nil for first time users AND returning users
     if error == nil {
         guard let uid = authResult?.user.uid else { return }
         let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users/\(uid)")
         //update realtime database here
     }
}
```

It works fine for the first time user. The issue is when it is returning user.Basically I need two different actions for the first time user and returning users. The difference is for returning users, I do not add anything to the database

P.S. I followed the official document from firebase in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple)

Comment: Once user authenticated the state will save in firebase so you don't need to re authenticate  user every time check `Auth.auth().currentUser == null` if current user null you need to reauthenticate and for the first time you can use a user default properite

Comment: I am just little confused about reauthentication process. We always check `Auth.auth().currentUser == null` if it is nil, it's a new user so we create new entry in the database and if it s NOT nil, we just proceed as normal. Then we should use `reauthenticate`?

Comment: @KamalUpasena As soon as Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) is called, current user is NOT nil.

Comment: you don't need to use re authenticate once user sign in it will be saved in the firebase.

Comment: @KamalUpasena Then how should I tell it is new user or returning one?

Comment: Auth.auth().currentUser will return you a returning user if this object is null user will be a new user if the object is not null user will be a returning user

Comment: @KamalUpasena Thanks but As soon as Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) is called, current user is NOT nil.
That means Auth.auth().currentUser is always nil before Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) is called and is never nil when Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) is called. This true for both cases

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following works

```
guard let uid = authResult?.user.uid else { return }
let db = Database.database().reference()
 db.child("Users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (DataSnapshot) in
     if DataSnapshot.hasChild(uid){
        //Existing user. No need to add anything to database
     }else{
        //New user. Add/Update database with some default values
     }
```

I don't know if this is the best approach or not but works for me for now